# MPL for_each to use functor with more parameters

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use compile time (MPL) for_each to check if given input variable is in MPL array and get and get the output variable from MPL array again. I'm trying to use function object with 2 parameters the MPL type and the input.

```
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


using namespace std;

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;


typedef mpl::range_c<char,1,5> range5;
typedef mpl::list<
mpl::int_<1>
, mpl::int_<5>
, mpl::int_<31>
, mpl::int_<14>
, mpl::int_<51>
>  out_type;


template <class T> struct id {};
struct do_this_wrapper {
    static char stat_c ;
    template<typename U> inline void operator()(int i, U )
    {
        if (i == U::value)
        {
            do_this_wrapper::stat_c = mpl::at_c<out_type,U::value>::type::value;
        }
    }
};


char do_this_wrapper::stat_c ;


int main()
{

    int x =1;
    boost::mpl::for_each<range5>(boost::bind(do_this_wrapper(), x, _1));

    return 0;
};
```

These are the errors

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from ../src/TestProj3.cpp:2627:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper>’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::arg<1> > >’
../src/TestProj3.cpp:2665:70:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘struct do_this_wrapper’
     typedef typename F::result_type type;
                                     ^
In file included from ../src/TestProj3.cpp:2617:0:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/for_each.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::mpl::aux::for_each_impl<false>::execute(Iterator*, LastIterator*, TransformFunc*, F) [with Iterator = boost::mpl::r_iter<mpl_::integral_c<char, '\001'> >; LastIterator = boost::mpl::r_iter<mpl_::integral_c<char, '\005'> >; TransformFunc = boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::na>; F = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::arg<1> > >]’:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/for_each.hpp:101:97:   required from ‘void boost::mpl::for_each(F, Sequence*, TransformOp*) [with Sequence = boost::mpl::range_c<char, '\001', '\005'>; TransformOp = boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::na>; F = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::arg<1> > >]’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/for_each.hpp:111:38:   required from ‘void boost::mpl::for_each(F, Sequence*) [with Sequence = boost::mpl::range_c<char, '\001', '\005'>; F = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::arg<1> > >]’
../src/TestProj3.cpp:2665:71:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/mpl/for_each.hpp:75:25: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, do_this_wrapper, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<int>, boost::arg<1> > >) (mpl_::integral_c<char, '\001'>&)’
         aux::unwrap(f, 0)(boost::get(x));
```

I would to ask is this possible to use in this way and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the BOOST_RESULT_OF protocol for `do_this_wrapper`:

```
    typedef void result_type;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df08e4246a4c929)**

```
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


using namespace std;

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;


typedef mpl::range_c<char,1,5> range5;
typedef mpl::list<
mpl::int_<1>
, mpl::int_<5>
, mpl::int_<31>
, mpl::int_<14>
, mpl::int_<51>
>  out_type;


template <class T> struct id {};
struct do_this_wrapper {
    typedef void result_type;
    static char stat_c ;
    template<typename U> inline void operator()(int i, U )
    {
        if (i == U::value)
        {
            do_this_wrapper::stat_c = mpl::at_c<out_type,U::value>::type::value;
        }
    }
};


char do_this_wrapper::stat_c ;


int main()
{

    int x =1;
    boost::mpl::for_each<range5>(boost::bind(do_this_wrapper(), x, _1));

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: if I change 
   typedef mpl::range_c<char,1,5> range5;
 with
    typedef mpl::list<
    mpl::int_<1>
    , mpl::int_<5>
    , mpl::int_<31>
    , mpl::int_<14>
    , mpl::int_<51>
    >  inp_type;

the other change is 

   boost::mpl::for_each<inp_type>(boost::bind(do_this_wrapper(), x, _1));


I've got these errors

...
     error: no type named ‘item’ in ‘struct boost::mpl::l_end’
...
     error: no type named ‘next’ ...
                                           
I've try same fix as result_type the result is same
would be thankfull for detailed descriprtion or sth to read
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post SSCCEs so I can just show it? You need a nested struct template `result` like: `template <typename...> struct result { typedef void type; };` likely (but I can't read that comment so I can't be more specific. See [BOOST_RESULT_OF protocol](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of) again)

Comment: NB. Some libraries allow the use of C++11 features to remove the need for the RESULT_OF protocol (I don't know whether MPL supports this). You can try to activate it by `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` before including any boost headers

Comment: Sehe because I'm new in Stack overflow I answer my question ,(maybe a bit supid), but I need fast answer could you please look.

Comment: Instead of posting an "answer", just edit the question (unless that changed the whole question, in which case you should just post a new question)